# Append one bit at the end of a binary number in C

Tags: c, binary, sha256

I'd like to add one single bit to a binary number in C, I'm pretty new to C, so please don't judge me because of such questions. I'd be very happy and a answer would be very helpful :)
Here's my code block:

```
void helloworldToBinary () {
    int i;  
    char *string = "hello world";
    for(i = 0 ; i < 8 * strlen(string); i++)
        printf("%d", 0 != (string[i/8] & 1 << (~i&7)));
            
    printf("\n");
}
```

If it helps, this is the output now:

```
0110100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000111011101101111011100100110110001100100
```

And this is the Output I'd want:

```
01101000011001010110110001101100011011110010000001110111011011110111001001101100011001001
```

Comment: Change `printf("\n");` to `printf("1\n");`?

Comment: Thanks pretty obvious I guess 

Comment: Edit the post to state whether you just need the bit added in output or need it in memory in the program. Edit the post to provide a [mre], which should include a complete program that other people can compile and execute with no changes or additions, so it must have a `main` routine and the appropriate `#include` directives.